Understanding srcset, sizes, and devicePixelRatio behavior with breakpoints
I'm trying to understand how the srcset and sizes attributes work in conjunction with devicePixelRatio on different devices. Here’s a scenario I’m looking at:
<img
  srcset="new-york-skyline-wide.jpg 3724w, new-york-skyline-4by3.jpg 1600w"
  sizes="100vw"
/>

enter link description here

When devicePixelRatio = 1, the breakpoint is at 1600px. Above 1600px, the browser uses new-york-skyline-wide.jpg (3724w), and below 1600px, it uses new-york-skyline-4by3.jpg (1600w).

When devicePixelRatio = 2, the breakpoint is at 1200px. Above 1200px, the browser uses new-york-skyline-wide.jpg (3724w), and below 1200px, it uses new-york-skyline-4by3.jpg (1600w).


I’m particularly puzzled by why the breakpoint changes to 1200px when devicePixelRatio = 2. How exactly does the browser decide which image to load based on this breakpoint shift?

See documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/srcset or simpler description  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_source_srcset.asp. In any case src attribute of img is required.

I've already added the src, but why breakpoint is at 1200px when devicePixelRatio = 2?

I would recommend you to use picture template for flexibility.
